# Why there are three newline (0a in binary) after matching?

Tags: awk

```
~$ string="221.11.165.237xxxx221.11.165.233\n
219.158.9.97ttttt219.158.19.137"
~$ echo $string > /tmp/test.txt
```

Now to check the real string in binary.

```
~$ xxd  /tmp/test.txt
00000000: 3232 312e 3131 2e31 3635 2e32 3337 7878  221.11.165.237xx
00000010: 7878 3232 312e 3131 2e31 3635 2e32 3333  xx221.11.165.233
00000020: 5c6e 2032 3139 2e31 3538 2e39 2e39 3774  \n 219.158.9.97t
00000030: 7474 7474 3231 392e 3135 382e 3139 2e31  tttt219.158.19.1
00000040: 3337 0a                                  37
```

we can see only one `0a` at the end of string.
Split the string with ip address

```
~$  echo "$string" | awk -v RS='([0-9]+\\.){3}[0-9]+' '{print $0}' > /tmp/test1.txt


~$ xxd  /tmp/test1.txt
00000000: 0a78 7878 780a 5c6e 0a0a 7474 7474 740a  .xxxx.\n..ttttt.
00000010: 0a0a
```

Why there are three newline `0a`  at the end of the file?
In my opnion there may be two newline `0a`  at the end ,one is previous ,other is created by print function in awk,which result in the third `0a`?
Why the result is not the following:

```
~$ xxd  /tmp/test1.txt
00000000: 0a78 7878 780a 5c6e 0a0a 7474 7474 740a  .xxxx.\n..ttttt.
00000010: 0a
                                ..
```

It is more clear to watch the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Could you please let us know what is your requirement clearly? Please post sample Input and expected sample output in code tags.

Comment: Please check the end of  result `xxd /tmp/test1.txt`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## you are adding 3 new lines

`1)` in string - remove `\n`

`2)` `echo` - by default adds new line - use `echo -n`

`3)` awk `print` - use `printf %s`

## after removing the newlines:

```
  set string="221.11.165.237xxxx221.11.165.233" ;
  echo -n "$string" | awk -v RS='([0-9]+\\.){3}[0-9]+' '{printf "%s", $0}'
```